# Define Method Based on Existing Method in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to metaprogram a way to define bang methods based on predicate methods. Right now I have the behavior I want working with `method_missing`:

```
class PredicateBang
  def true?
    true
  end

  def false?
    false
  end

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if bang_match = /\A([^?]+)!\z/.match(method.to_s)
      predicate_method = :"#{bang_match[1]}?"
      if respond_to?(predicate_method)
        unless send(predicate_method, *args, &block)
          raise "#{predicate_method} is false"
        end
        return
      end
    end
    super.method_missing(method, *args, &block)
  end
end

PredicateBang.new.true!
PredicateBang.new.false! # false? is false (RuntimeError)
```

Instead of overriding `method_missing`, however, I'd like to define the methods dynamically by iterating over the `instance_methods(false)` and using `define_method` to create a bang method for any method that ends in a question mark with matching parameters, but I'm not sure how to reflect on all the details of the methods.

[`Method#parameters`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-parameters) seemed like a decent first step but I'm not sure how to translate that to block parameters or handle default values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `Method#parameters`, you can use `*args` to capture the arguments being passed (including default values) and use a `&block` style parameter to pass any block along as you were doing with `method_missing`. So a basic example would be

```
define_method(bang_method) do |*args, &block|
  unless send(predicate_method, *args, &block)
    raise "#{predicate_method} is false"
  end
end
```

Now to add write a method `add_bang_methods(clazz)` which will add a bang method for each predicate on a class, you can use `instance_methods` as you mentioned to get the list of methods and `class_eval` to define those methods in the context of the class. So a rough outline would be:

```
def add_bang_methods(clazz)
  clazz.instance_methods.each do |method_name|
    if predicate_match = /\A([^?]+)\?\z/.match(method_name.to_s)
      bang_method = :"#{predicate_match[1]}!"
      clazz.class_eval do
        define_method(bang_method) do |*args, &block|
          unless send(method_name, *args, &block)
            raise "#{method_name} is false"
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Super cool. I never knew you could pass a splat as a block parameter. I'm guessing there's no way to reflect on default values then?

Comment: `SomeClass.instance_method(:method_name).parameters` will give you a list of the parameters for that method name, including details of which are required and which ones are optional, but it won't give you the default values.

Comment: I ended up evolving this use case into my first published gem, [Interrobang](https://github.com/fny/interrobang). Thanks for the help!